# How to return results where multiple words appears more times

Tags: mysql

When i use multiple words in Boolean Full-Text Searches, InnoDB Engine i expect to return relevance results where words appears more times, but for some reason this is not happen.

My question is how to sort results where words appears more times

for example if i have phrase: new car BMW , i expect 1st few results to include all 3 word then next resutls to include any 2 word and at the end results where include only 1 of the word

[Example of DB and query](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/x5nxJH7qfADZFiJLPQztxr/0)

The problem in query is results with score_name 0.6127969622612 are below when they match 2 word and results with score 3.12283992767334 match only one word

for example you can look at results with:

product_id: 16380, score_name=3.12283992767334, match only one word(**повдигаща**)

product_id: 29953, score_name=0.6127969622612, match 2 words(**разтегателна**, **маса**)

How to sort 1st results where words appears more times ?

Anyone can help to solved this problem ?

Query

```
SELECT pd.product_id, pd.name,
CASE
WHEN name = 'разтегателна повдигаща се маса' THEN 200
WHEN name LIKE 'разтегателна повдигаща се маса%' THEN 100
WHEN name LIKE '% разтегателна повдигаща се маса %' THEN 50
WHEN name LIKE '%разтегателна повдигаща се маса' THEN 50
ELSE 
MATCH(name) AGAINST('разтегателна повдигаща се маса' IN BOOLEAN MODE) END AS score_name
FROM product_description pd
WHERE
MATCH(name) AGAINST('разтегателна повдигаща се маса' IN BOOLEAN MODE) 
ORDER BY score_name DESC
LIMIT 80
```

DB

```
CREATE TABLE `product_description` (
`product_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
`name` varchar(255) NOT NULL
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;


ALTER TABLE `product_description`
ADD PRIMARY KEY (`product_id`),
ADD KEY `name` (`name`);
ALTER TABLE `product_description` ADD FULLTEXT KEY `name_full_text` (`name`);
```

Comment: i have similar problem did you find any solution ?

Comment: Does FULLTEXT work for non-English text?

Comment: The FT algorithm also takes into consideration how "rare" the word is.  If повдигаща occurs in only one row, then that row may get a high score.

Comment: @RickJames yes FULLTEXT is working for non-english phrase

Answer (score 0):

https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/fulltext-boolean.html

If the "relevancy ranking" for повдигаща was high and that word was missing from the other rows, then the numbers received makes sense.  Find the relevance for each word independently -- this may help confirm my hypothesis.

Consider "requiring" the words:

```
AGAINST('+разтегателна +повдигаща се +маса' IN BOOLEAN MODE)
```

Note that I did not require 'се', since that would mess up if `innodb_ft_min_token_size` = 3 or more.

Comment: i got that but "+" wont help because wont match other records where has only 2 words like "разтегателна маса", the question still "How to sort 1st results where words appears more times "